# WPF - Custom Validation Rule for Record Insertion In DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dataset

Now I have a window to operate the records in one of my DB tables, which looks like:

[image]

I got this `DataGrid` control by dragging it from `Data Source` Tab. And that data source is actually a `DataSet` item I created in VS 2015, which means some strongly typed database operating classes are automatically generated in a .xsd file. So, you see, basically, everything behind this `Datagrid` is generated automatically, both the xaml and C# code.
[image]
[image]

By default, when you insert a new record, the data you type in the cell will be checked against its type, if you type in something not as expected, a red exclamation will show up in the first cell. For example, the IRD column in my table is int type, if you type in some symbols other than digit, you will get that red exclamation.

What I want to do now, is restrain user type in 8 to 9 digits, for example, if user types in only 3 digits: 346, he/she would see the red exclamation, and cannot proceed to insert the record.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that you are using `DataTable` as `ItemsSource` for `DataGrid`? If it is, so let me show how you can validate your cell:

```
this.YourDataTable.ColumnChanging += YourDataTableColumnChangingStuff;

private void YourDataTableColumnChangingStuff(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
   private void EmployeeDataTable_ColumnChanging(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
    {
         //if you want to leave previous value 
        if ("incorrect value" != e.ProposedValue.ToString())
            e.ProposedValue = e.Row.ItemArray[e.Column.Ordinal];
        else
        {
            //if you want to set new value
            e.ProposedValue = "new value";
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank @StepUp, I believe we need more, just set the column error is not enough to stop the record from being inserted into the DataTable.rows collection. I tried.